# mobile broadband in network setting missing

Tags: 11.10, networking, broadband, 3g

I'm trying to connect to the internet using mobile broadband network (3G) in Ubuntu 11.10, but the mobile broadband tab (the one to enable/disable mobile broadband) in network setting seems to be missing.

how should I enable it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!